# Moving ul element vertically

Tags: javascript, jquery, setinterval

I need your help.

I am trying to move UL element vertically using counter and setinterval method but unfortunately it seems that there exist a problem with my code, because sometimes the i counter repeat it self when its value being 2 or it backs to 2 when it reach to the limit.

this is my code

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
     var length = $("#container ul li").length;
     var i = 0;
     function animate(){
         var mtop = i*(-245);
         console.log(i+" if yes ");
         $("#container ul").animate({top:mtop+"px"},1000);
         i++; 
     }
     setInterval(function(){
         if(i<length){ 
             animate();
         }else{
             i=0;
             animate();     
         }
     },2000);

 </script>
```

Comment: You reset `i` whenever it equals `length`, so of course it will repeat itself. You also never stop the interval, so it will keep doing this forever. Is that what you want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it seems that there exist a conflict with another code try to change your code like this

```
<script type="text/javascript">

                 var length = $("#container ul li").length;
                 var o = 0;
                 function animate(){

                     var mtop = o*(-245);

                     $("#container ul").animate({top:mtop+"px"},1000);

                 }

                setInterval(function(){
                   if(o==length)
                   {
                        o=0;
                   }
                   animate();
                 },2000); 
</script>
```